# Laravel 5 validator passing when it should fail

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

I am validating an array in Laravel 5.7 but the validator passes when I expect it to fail.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

        'user_reg_email' => 'required|max:255|email|exists:users,email',
        'service_start_date' => 'required|before_or_equal:today',
        'service_end_date' => 'nullable|after:service_start_date',
        'role' => 'array|min:1|unique:provider_user,role,NULL,id,user_email,' . $request->user_reg_email . ',provider_domain,' . $request->prov,

    ]);
```

**The payload is as below:**

```
    {

        _token: "d5VYhirRAn3Zb9bCKHKQiuLNXkHfEP4hEs0bAZvj",
        prov: "email.com",
        user_reg_email: "john@email.com",
        service_start_date: "2019-03-03",
        service_end_date: null,
        role: [
            null
        ],
    }
```

The role validation passes but I expect it to fail. How do I get the expected results?

Comment: What exactly are you validating it for?

Comment: The table primary key comprises of 'provider_domain', 'user_email' and 'role' and needs to be unique. This validation works correctly. The part that passes when it should fail is 'array|min:1'. This should fail when you pass a NULL array.

Comment: I think using a required validation on it should do the trick.Otherwise try making a custom validation using Validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'role' => 'array,...'` will validate that the `role` field is an array, which it is.

To validate the items *within* the array, you also need to include this rule:

```
'role.*' => unique:provider_user,...
```